# How to use Letsencrypt certificate for GKE Ingress?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, lets-encrypt

I have just recieve SSL certificate from Letsencrypt and I want to use it with GKE Ingress. I was using self-signed certificate before and I am a bit confused about file names of my certificates. Here is what i have in /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN_NAME folder (description from the README):

- `privkey.pem`  : the private key for your certificate.
- `fullchain.pem`: the certificate file used in most server software.
- `chain.pem`    : used for OCSP stapling in Nginx >=1.3.7.
- `cert.pem`     : will break many server configurations

---

And here is what i had before, the keys was created with openssl command below:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ./ssl.key -out ./ssl.crt
openssl dhparam -out ./ssl.pem 2048
```

- `ssl.crt`
- `ssl.key`
- `ssl.pem`

---

My question is - which files from the letsencrypt folder should I use?

- `ssl.crt` -> ?
- `ssl.key` -> ?
- `ssl.pem` -> ?

Answer (score 1):

Trial and error method and a little bit of wikipedia show me that:

- `ssl.crt` is the same as `cert.pem`
- `ssl.key` is the same as `privkey.pem`
- `ssl.pem` is DH Params, crypto-something that can be used without changes